# Get total of records of children in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `shop_item` (parents) and `shop_products` (children).

In the table `shop_products` there is column `shop_item_id`, which indicates, what is his parent. Some parents have plenty of children. In the table `shop_products` there is also column `shop_number`, which is unique. My goal is to find all parents having children starting with `123` (for example). I can achive it by:

```
SELECT shop_products.shop_number, shop_products.shop_item_id, shop_item.*
FROM shop_products,
     shop_item
WHERE shop_products.shop_number LIKE '123%'
  AND shop_item.id = shop_products.shop_item_id;
```

This one works, but I want also get number of these children (because as a result I get parents), but I don't know if it is even possible.

**EDIT:**

Example table `shop_item`:

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | name  | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
| 1  | test1 | ... |
| 2  | test2 | ... |
| 3  | test3 | ... |
| 4  | test4 | ... |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Example table `shop_products`:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| id | shop_item_id | shop_number | ... |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
| 1  | 1            | 12345       | ... |
| 2  | 2            | 1234567     | ... |
| 3  | 1            | 14486       | ... |
| 4  | 3            | 32333       | ... |
| 5  | 1            | 12399       | ... |
| 6  | 4            | 12325       | ... |
| 7  | 2            | 25511       | ... |
| 8  | 1            | 42387       | ... |
+----+--------------+-------------+-----+
```

Expecting result:

```
+----+----------+-----+
| id | children | ... |
+----+----------+-----+
| 1  | 2        | ... |
| 2  | 1        | ... |
| 4  | 1        | ... |
+----+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Add some sample table and the expected result (just enough to describe the problem).

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use proper, explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use `JOIN`.

Then, the answer to your question is `GROUP BY`.  So, to find the parents

```
SELECT s.shop_number, COUNT(*)
FROM shop_products p JOIN
     shop_item i
     ON p.shop_number LIKE '123%' AND
        i.id = p.shop_item_id
GROUP BY s.shop_number;
```

If you want the original detailed data with the column added, then use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.shop_number, si.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM shop_item si2 WHERE si2.id = p.shop_item_id) as cnt
FROM shop_products p JOIN
     shop_item i
     ON p.shop_number LIKE '123%' AND
        i.id = p.shop_item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you needed to get only the common items (i.e. only the children that has parents and the parents that has children):

```
select shop_products.shop_number, shop_products.shop_item_id, 
       shop_item.*, Count(shop_products.shop_item_id) over (partition by shop_products.shop_item_id) as ChildrenCount
from shop_item
inner join shop_products
on shop_products.shop_item_id = shop_item.shop_item_id
where shop_products.shop_number LIKE '123%'
```

else if you want to get the data regardless the common use Left Outer Join:

```
select shop_products.shop_number, shop_products.shop_item_id, 
   shop_item.*, Count(shop_products.shop_item_id) over (partition by shop_products.shop_item_id) as ChildrenCount
from shop_item
left outer join shop_products
on shop_products.shop_item_id = shop_item.shop_item_id
where shop_products.shop_number LIKE '123%'
```